# Does it overfit if the nested models are trained on the same data

Tags: machine-learning

Does it overfit if I build a machine learning model where it use the output from another machine learning model while both models are trained on the same data?
Basically I was wondering if I can use the KNN prediction result as an input for a deep neural network model while both of the models are trained on the very same data.

Answer (score 1):

Nesting machine learning models is possible. For example, neuronal networks can be seen as multiple nested perceptrons (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron).

However you are right - nesting machine learning models increase the VC-dimension (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VC_dimension) of your complete machine learning system and thus the risk of overfitting.

In practice cross-validation is often used in order to reduce the risk of overfitting.

**Edit:**

@MatiasValdenegro +1 for pointing towards a point I do not specify very clearly in my answer. Pure cross-validation can indeed only be used in order to detect overfitting.

However when we training certain machine learning systems like neuronal networks, it is possible to use some sort of cross-validation in order to reduce the risk of overfitting. In order to do so, we simply discard e.g. 10% of the training data for training. Then after each training round, the trained machine learning system is evaluated on the discarded training data. Once the trained neuronal network is getting worse on the discarded part, the training algorithm stops. This is for example done by the python pybrain (http://pybrain.org/) library.

Comment: Cross validation is not used to "reduce the risk of overfitting", just to detect it.